# How to style this with css?

Tags: html, css, web

Wondering what is the best way to style this with css? I know `float` could make it happen but I don't think it is a good idea.

```
Love  Love is a variety of different feelings, 
      states, and attitudes that ranges from
      interpersonal affection to pleasure.

Day   A day is a unit of time. In common
      usage, it is an interval equal to 24 
      hours.
```

.

```
<li>
    <span>Love</span>
    <span>Love is a variety of different feelings, states, and attitudes that ranges from interpersonal affection to pleasure.</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Day</span>
    <span>A day is a unit of time. In common usage, it is an interval equal to 24 hours.</span>
</li>
```

Comment: `best` is a very arbitrary term. Best for what? Minimal amount of css? Easiest to maintain? Most technical? Least technical? Most aesthetically pleasing design? Most aesthetically pleasing design according to you? Most aesthetically pleasing design according to your client? Least amount of time required to accomplish what you want? What's the end result that you're actually after?

Comment: Start by fixing your markup. You have a definition list there, not an (un)ordered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [wonderous `display:table-*` options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/display):

```
li {
    display:table-row;
}
li > span {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:3px;
}
```

[As seen on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7emb34o/)

And gives this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Use `dl`, `dt` and `dd` tags for this**

```
<dl>            
    <dt>Name: </dt>
    <dd>John Don</dd>

    <dt>Age: </dt>
    <dd>23</dd>

    <dt>Gender: </dt>
    <dd>Male</dd>

    <dt>Day of Birth:</dt>
    <dd>12th May 1986</dd>
</dl>
```

**css**

```
dl {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

dl dt {

    color:#000;
    float:left; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    padding:5px;  
    width:100px; 
}

dl dd {
    margin:2px 0; 
    padding:5px 0;
}
```

Here is the output: http://jsfiddle.net/jemz2q5m/5/

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

css:

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
ul > li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#ccc
}

ul > li div { display:table; }
ul > li div span { display:table-cell; }
ul > li div span.one { width:100px; }
```

check out jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r31a4p3d/

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why float is a bad idea? Try this:

```css
li {
    clear:both;
    list-style-type:none;
}

li span:first-child {
    float:left;
    padding:0 20px 20px 0;
    display:block;
    min-width:30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mz46oyee/

Comment: Because css tables are easier to use.

Answer (score -1):

Your structure suggest a table behavior here like :

```
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Love</th>
        <td>Love is a variety of different feelings, states, and attitudes that ranges from interpersonal affection to pleasure.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <td>A day is a unit of time. In common usage, it is an interval equal to 24 hours</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/4dohxmn8/

Comment: **No.** This is not tabular data. Tables are for tabular data, not presentation!

Comment: Especially not when this can be done with CSS, without changing the markup

Comment: How is this not tabular data? I mean, it's not very exhaustive but still. Anyways, a definition list would be the _most correct_ way to mark this up.

Comment: This is a list of definition, table can be able here and purpose the structure that he wanted to without css. Render is a fact SEO another